# How to use if in a for statement in Python

Tags: python

I have an array tab2(number are in a range(22) ).I want to be able to somme the occurrence in tab2 of each number(0....21)and print("#")*occurrence it

```
In [104]: for i in  np.array(range(22)): 
     ...:     cpt=0 
     ...:     for j in tab2: 
     ...:         if i==j:print("#",end='') 
     ...:     print("")                   
     ...:     print("Le numéro ",i," est présent ",cpt," fois")
```

All i get is 
(It's like the "if:" isn't compute)

```
Le numéro  0  est présent  0  fois

Le numéro  1  est présent  0  fois

Le numéro  2  est présent  0  fois

Le numéro  3  est présent  0  fois

Le numéro  4  est présent  0  fois

Le numéro  5  est présent  0  fois

Le numéro  6  est présent  0  fois

Le numéro  7  est présent  0  fois

Le numéro  8  est présent  0  fois

Le numéro  9  est présent  0  fois

Le numéro  10  est présent  0  fois

Le numéro  11  est présent  0  fois

Le numéro  12  est présent  0  fois

Le numéro  13  est présent  0  fois

Le numéro  14  est présent  0  fois

Le numéro  15  est présent  0  fois

Le numéro  16  est présent  0  fois

Le numéro  17  est présent  0  fois

Le numéro  18  est présent  0  fois

Le numéro  19  est présent  0  fois

Le numéro  20  est présent  0  fois
```

Comment: What is `tab2`? Please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us. Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: event with cpt+=1 in the second "for " it donsent change,(forgot to mentione that)

Comment: I suspect that the computer is right, and you will realize your mistake once you try to create a [mcve]

Comment: tab2 isn't what you think it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want something like this?  increment the cpt counter in the if block

```
>>> tab2=(np.random.randint(low=1,high=100,size=100)
...
... )
>>>
>>> tab2
array([48, 23, 71,  8, 42, 28, 67, 65, 26, 94, 74, 60, 17, 56, 88, 94, 70,
       17, 35, 89, 19, 42, 67, 24, 52, 44,  3, 70, 84, 47, 24, 11, 31,  5,
       78, 99, 63, 13, 36, 67, 32, 39, 56, 71, 87, 20, 95, 39, 92, 64, 40,
       16, 59,  2, 65, 48, 16, 81, 54, 83, 51, 94, 79, 42, 20, 36, 97, 85,
       50, 99, 79, 70, 12, 46, 52,  7, 36, 24, 76, 17, 50, 49, 33, 49, 57,
       52, 41, 26, 25, 20,  9, 57, 94, 99,  8, 49, 75, 49, 81, 27])
>>> for i in range(22):
...   cpt=0
...   for j in tab2:
...     if j == i:
...       cpt+=1
...   print("")
...   print(i, " present ", cpt, "times")
...

(0, ' present ', 0, 'times')

(1, ' present ', 0, 'times')

(2, ' present ', 1, 'times')

(3, ' present ', 1, 'times')

(4, ' present ', 0, 'times')

(5, ' present ', 1, 'times')

(6, ' present ', 0, 'times')

(7, ' present ', 1, 'times')

(8, ' present ', 2, 'times')

(9, ' present ', 1, 'times')

(10, ' present ', 0, 'times')

(11, ' present ', 1, 'times')

(12, ' present ', 1, 'times')

(13, ' present ', 1, 'times')

(14, ' present ', 0, 'times')

(15, ' present ', 0, 'times')

(16, ' present ', 2, 'times')

(17, ' present ', 3, 'times')

(18, ' present ', 0, 'times')

(19, ' present ', 1, 'times')

(20, ' present ', 3, 'times')

(21, ' present ', 0, 'times')
>>>
```

Comment: Tried but doesnt work ,(i am a noob) so i forgot to mention that i working in a scrapy shell